# JavaFX combobox selected item disappears after filtering the combobox list

Tags: javafx

I've got a simple application that displays an item that has been selected from a combobox in a table. However, when the item is selected in the combobox, the remaining items are filtered to include items who's names are included in the selected item. For example, in the following MCVE if you were to select "Apple" from the combobox, the controlling list would be filtered to contain "Apple" and "Pineapple".

Occasionally the combobox will reset to no longer display the selected item after the filter is applied.
The problem occurs when you select an item that doesn't have any other items in the resulting filtered list. For example if you select "Banana" or "Pineapple" from the combobox, instead of displaying the selected item the combobox will display the prompt text.

Please see the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("ComboBox Issues");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Fruit> fruityTable;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Fruit> fruitSelector;

    private ObservableList<Fruit> selectedFruits;

    private ObservableList<Predicate<Fruit>> filterCriteria;

    private Predicate<Fruit> fruitFilter;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fruit, String> fruitNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fruit, String> fruitColorColumn;

    @FXML
    void addSelectedFruit(ActionEvent event) {
        if (fruitSelector.getValue() != null) {
            Fruit selectedFruit = getSelectedFruitFromComboBox();
            final String name = selectedFruit.getName().toLowerCase();
            fruitFilter = selectableFruits -> selectableFruits.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name);
            Platform.runLater(() -> filterCriteria.add(fruitFilter));
            this.selectedFruits.add(selectedFruit);
            event.consume();
        }
    }

    private Fruit getSelectedFruitFromComboBox() {
        return fruitSelector.getValue();
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        Fruit apple = new Fruit("Apple", "Red");
        Fruit pineapple = new Fruit("Pineapple", "Brown");
        Fruit banana = new Fruit("Banana", "Yellow");
        ObservableList<Fruit> fruitSelectorItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        fruitSelectorItems.addAll(apple, pineapple, banana);
        initializeFruitSelector(fruitSelectorItems);
        initializeFruitTable();
    }

    private void initializeFruitSelector(ObservableList<Fruit> fruitSelectorItems) {
        FilteredList<Fruit> filteredFruit = new FilteredList<>(fruitSelectorItems, x -> true);
        fruitSelector.setItems(filteredFruit);
        filterCriteria = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        filteredFruit.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
            filterCriteria.stream().reduce(x-> true, Predicate::and), filterCriteria));
        fruitSelector.setConverter(createFruitChooserConverter());
    }

    private StringConverter<Fruit> createFruitChooserConverter() {
        return new StringConverter<Fruit>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Fruit item) {
                if (item == null ) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return item.getName();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Fruit fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    private void initializeFruitTable() {
        selectedFruits = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        fruitNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> formatFruitNameColumnText(cellData.getValue()));
        fruitColorColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> formatFruitColorColumnText(cellData.getValue()));
        fruityTable.setItems(selectedFruits);
    }

    private ObservableValue<String> formatFruitColorColumnText(Fruit fruit) {
        ReadOnlyStringWrapper color;
        if (fruit == null) {
            color = null;
        } else {
            color = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(fruit.getColor());
        }
        return color;
    }

    private ObservableValue<String> formatFruitNameColumnText(Fruit fruit) {
        ReadOnlyStringWrapper name;
        if (fruit == null) {
            name = null;
        } else {
            name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(fruit.getName());
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

Fruit.java

```
package sample;

public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private String color;

    Fruit(String name, String color){
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="fruityTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="201.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="fruitNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="fruitColorColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Color" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <ComboBox fx:id="fruitSelector" onAction="#addSelectedFruit" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Choose a fruit" />
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

This seems to be a bug with the JavaFX combobox, but I haven't seen anyone with a similar issue (perhaps because it's an uncommon requirement to filter the same combobox after a selection?) Or am I doing something incorrectly?

**Edit**

As James_D notes in the comments, this issue is not present in newer version of Java (Java 8u131 at least). I am forced to use Java 8u25 for now however. The main reason I am concerned with this issue is because it allows the user to select the same item twice. So a solution that prevents the user from duplicating items in the table would be acceptable to me.

Comment: You seem to be combining the new filter with the existing filter each time something is selected. (Why? That's not the requirement you describe.) So if you select "Apple" and then select "Banana", the list will be filtered to include only those items that contain the text "Apple" *and* contain the text "Banana", resulting in an empty list.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that when writing this mcve. The actual application applies some additional logic to determine when to filter the list. It will only ever apply a filter once. The method I am using to filter the list is a little overkill for my purposes. I actually stole it from one of your answers after trying the first two methods you suggested in an attempt to fix this issue.

Comment: I just tried running this and it seems to work as expected. (You can't actually choose "Apple" and then "Banana" as I described in the previous comment, because after choosing "Apple", "Banana" is filtered.) I can't reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Great. Must be a version issue. I am running Java 8u25. Can you think of anyway to keep that item selected? Without triggering the action command?

Comment: Can you update to a more recent version? I would recommend using at least 8u60. As I said, I can't reproduce the problem, so it's hard to recommend a fix...

Comment: I updated my MCVE project JDK to 8u131 and can confirm that it is indeed an issue with 8u25. Unfortunately, I am unable to update the actual project's JDK at this time. Thanks for helping me confirm it is a version issue @James_D. I believe [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095352) is the bug that is causing my headache, and it looks like it was fixed in 8u60 as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@James_D helped me figure out that I was experiencing a bug that has been fixed in newer versions of Java. But since I am currently unable to update my applications version of Java, I still needed to figure out a way to prevent the user from being able to add duplicate items to the list. Once I phrased the problem in this way, it was easy to determine a decent work around.

I modified the filter to exclude the selected item in the filtered list.

```
fruitFilter = selectableFruits -> selectableFruits.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name) && !selectableFruits.getName().toLowerCase().equals(name);
```

The combobox still doesn't display the selected item (it can't now, because it's no longer in the list) but the user wont be able to select a duplicate item any more.